.csv file not importing in the PostgreSQL table
I have created a Database named Nova and a table named product
this is the code of the table
CREATE TABLE products (
    pro_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    pro_category VARCHAR(50),
    pro_name VARCHAR(50),
    pro_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    pro_desc TEXT,
    rating INT
);

This is the csv file that i am importing to the table
then I have stored a dummy data in a csv file but its not getting imported to the table.
This is what i am getting when i am importing the csv file
This is my first time creating a project using Database.
i have imported the file but its not getting imported rather giving an error, I have given screenshot of the error above.

KIndly go through this article https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/

Can you check and share the postgres' logs? to see the errors


Do not use images per this Don't upload images.  2) The error messages as is are of no use. You might try clicking on View Processes to see if there is more information. Otherwise follow the suggestion from @AnthonySotolongo . 3) Do you already have data in the table, where there maybe a conflict on the pro_id Primary Key?


You have not included a screenshot of the error, only of a message indicating that an error exists.  Click the sheet of paper icon in the table of errors to see the error message.  And try to include it as text, not (or in addition to) image.
